# how to get list of all modified files in pipeline jenkins?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using multibranch pipeline and i need to get the list of modified files.

i tried

`git diff $PREVIOUS_COMMIT $COMMIT`

but they have the same SHA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get list of changed files since last build in Jenkins/Hudson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260383/how-to-get-list-of-changed-files-since-last-build-in-jenkins-hudson)

Comment: @Mahmoud this is not necessary a duplicate. There are additional possibilities with Jenkins Pipelines.

Comment: @Mahmoud, no this is not a duplicate. I already check the proposed solutions on the link you provide.

Comment: You're right, sorry for the bad intervention

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [this article at CloudBees](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/217630098-How-to-access-Changelogs-in-a-Pipeline-Job-), you can access such information inside a pipeline also without white-listing (using Sandbox / script security, compared to my other answer), starting from [workflow-support Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-support) version 2.2:

```java
def changeLogSets = currentBuild.changeSets
for (int i = 0; i < changeLogSets.size(); i++) {
    def entries = changeLogSets[i].items
    for (int j = 0; j < entries.length; j++) {
        def entry = entries[j]
        echo "${entry.commitId} by ${entry.author} on ${new Date(entry.timestamp)}: ${entry.msg}"
        def files = new ArrayList(entry.affectedFiles)
        for (int k = 0; k < files.size(); k++) {
            def file = files[k]
            echo "  ${file.editType.name} ${file.path}"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. This solution show me also the files changed on my librairy? how can i avoid this?

Comment: There's some option to the library step to disable the changelog.

Comment: `library(identifier: 'mylib', changelog: false)`

Comment: For me, this solution does not work. It gives me a lot of changes even I changed one file.

Comment: Then please ask a new question with sufficient detail.

Comment: @Adam I had the same issue and it was related to the scm clone options I used.
I set the following options to false: honorRefspec, shallow. After that it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Reference link: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/217630098

FYI:
Pipeline Supporting APIs Plugin 2.2 or above

You can use currentBuild.changeSets in a sandboxed build as you could see in the following example of Git:

```
def changeLogSets = currentBuild.changeSets
for (int i = 0; i < changeLogSets.size(); i++) {
    def entries = changeLogSets[i].items
    for (int j = 0; j < entries.length; j++) {
        def entry = entries[j]
        echo "${entry.commitId} by ${entry.author} on ${new Date(entry.timestamp)}: ${entry.msg}"
        def files = new ArrayList(entry.affectedFiles)
        for (int k = 0; k < files.size(); k++) {
            def file = files[k]
            echo "  ${file.editType.name} ${file.path}"
        }
    }
}
```

Pipeline Supporting APIs Plugin older than 2.2

You can use currentBuild.rawBuild.changeSets but this is not accessible from the sandbox. Following is an example of Git for a non-sandboxed build:

```
def changeLogSets = currentBuild.rawBuild.changeSets
for (int i = 0; i < changeLogSets.size(); i++) {
    def entries = changeLogSets[i].items
    for (int j = 0; j < entries.length; j++) {
        def entry = entries[j]
        echo "${entry.commitId} by ${entry.author} on ${new Date(entry.timestamp)}: ${entry.msg}"
        def files = new ArrayList(entry.affectedFiles)
        for (int k = 0; k < files.size(); k++) {
            def file = files[k]
            echo "  ${file.editType.name} ${file.path}"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access such information (after white-listing the API calls) via the `currentBuild` variable:

```java
currentBuild.rawBuild.getChangeSets().each { cs ->
  cs.getItems().each { item ->
    item.getAffectedFiles().each { f ->
      println f
    }
  }
}
```

Untested by myself (but makes sense). Source: [lsjostro's Gist](https://gist.github.com/lsjostro/3f410333ac90ecccfdc139079f585b3a).

Answer (score 2):

I guess this solution only list the changes in the current build, which in most of cases, is not useful in DevOps. What we need is the change set from the last successful build. I found another solution here:
Jenkins pipeline - An approach to get all commits since the last successful build:
https://gist.github.com/ftclausen/8c46195ee56e48e4d01cbfab19c41fc0