# Trigger jenkins build (maven) only if version not in nexus

Tags: jenkins

I'd like to trigger Jenkins build only if version specified in pom.xml is not available in my nexus repository. Any help appreciated :)

I could disallow nexus to overwrite existing version, but it is currently not an option

Comment: This may help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243593/how-to-trigger-a-build-only-if-changes-happen-on-particular-set-of-files