# How can Jenkins poll on a specific file and not the whole repo

Tags: git, jenkins

I know Jenkins can poll on a git repo change as a build trigger.

How can Jenkins poll on a specific file and not the whole repo?

[image]

Comment: Polling the repository would indicate a change in a file would it not?

Comment: Would https://stackoverflow.com/q/5243593/6309 help?

Comment: @Peter Reid but it would notify for files change that i don't want to trigger my jenkins job