# Jenkins git plugin, polling certain paths

Tags: git, jenkins

I have a jenkins job for a maven multi module project with this structure:

- Module A
- Module B
- desktop_App
- common
- ...

I want to execute the job that deploy the desktop_app only when changes are pushed to certain path. With git plugin it's supossed to do that but I put relative path on the white list field but scm ignore all commits

[image]

> Git Polling Log
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> Ignored commit 7a5aafc79ffe142a63b8a65ed183068fcc1d42fa: No paths
>   matched included region whitelist

How works this plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried changing the regex to:

- desktop_app/.*
- common/.*

This might be your problem.