# Jenkins: Run migrations only when migrations folder has changed

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I have a pipeline script, and would like to take different actions depending on the changes of the migrations folder.

Basically would be a workflow like this

1. Pull changes in the repository
2. Check if the `migrations/` folder has new migrations or changes
3. If changes are present, run migrations, if not, continue

I'm not sure how could I achieve this, I'm using version 2.1 and the git plugin. This repo is on a private server

Answer (score 0):

In your case, 'included region' feature from Git plugin should help. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9234776/10721592) answer for details.

So, for pipeline, you can generate the correct syntax using pipeline-syntax generator (under `http://<JENKINS_IP>:<JENKINS_PORT>/job/<PATH_TO_PIPELINE_JOB>/pipeline-syntax/` job in **Sample Step: checkout -> SCM: Git -> Additional Behaviours -> Polling ignores commits in certain paths**). It will be something like this:

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'PathRestriction', excludedRegions: '', includedRegions: 'migrations/.*']], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'test', url: 'http://test.com/test.git']]])
```

Check [this](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/) documentation for details (`extensions -> includedRegions`).

For job dsl syntax it will be like [this](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/pull/49#issuecomment-373460130):

```
scm {
    git {
        remote {
            ...
        }
        extensions {
            cleanBeforeCheckout()
            disableRemotePoll() // this is important for path restrictions to work
            configure { git ->
                git / 'extensions' / 'hudson.plugins.git.extensions.impl.PathRestriction' {
                    includedRegions "somepath/.*"
                    excludedRegions "README.md\n\\.gitignore\npom.xml"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you can use GitHub/GitLab/BitBucket webhooks to build a project when a change is pushed to repository.
See [this](https://medium.com/@mohan08p/jenkins-integration-with-bitbucket-github-webhook-25a191507cab) example for Github and BitBucket configuration and [this](https://jamalshahverdiev.wordpress.com/2018/02/07/jenkins-gitlab-integration-with-webhook/) example for GitLab configuration.

If you want to build the project only for changes in `migrations` folder and not for any changes in repository, you can configure comment regex for triggering a build and add this specific comment (e.g., "[changes in migrations folder]") to the commit every time you want to trigger a build.

Comment: Forgot to add that I'm using the git plugin, the repo is in a private server, That may be a valid approach, if there is no other way I'll probably do that. Though ideally I would like it to be based on the folder itself, my goal is to make this work with the minimal amount of manual intervention

Comment: Probably you can use 'included region' feature from Git plugin (see updated answer).

Comment: I saw that but I can't find that option, It should be under additional behaviors but I can't find it, is it not available for pipelines?

Comment: In pipelines it's under `extensions`. If you're using pipeline-syntax generator: you can find it in **Additional Behaviours -> Polling ignores commits in certain paths** option. Updated in answer with more details.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a way to do it directly with the plugin, but I only get the option for included regions if I add another branch source as "Single repository & branch", so for now I implemented this solution:

I added this to my Jenkinsfile, to check for changes on the `migrations/` folder

```
script {
    env.CONTAINS_MIGRATIONS = sh (
        script: 'git diff --name-only --diff-filter=AMDR --cached HEAD^',
        returnStdout: true
    ).trim()

    if (env.CONTAINS_MIGRATIONS.contains('migrations')) {
        // Do migrations related stuff
    }
}
```

I'm doing this considering that is unlikely to have filename conflicts, and if they happen is not a big deal