# How to trigger the Jenkins job specific folder inside branch

Tags: jenkins

[image]

Jenkins build based on update of specific folder inside Feature branch, i want to compile the code only in  specific folder code not entire branch code.
If i update made some changes on DataTypes it should compile only DataType code only not entire Feature branch code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to trigger a build only if changes happen on particular set of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243593/how-to-trigger-a-build-only-if-changes-happen-on-particular-set-of-files)