# How to build from a specific git revision in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, git-revision

I have a Jenkins build job with
`Source Code Management > GIT > Repository URL: https://GitHub_repo_url/branch_name`

this will pull the the **HEAD revision** out of the branch.

How can I pull code of **specified revision**?

Comment: Just below where you put the URL you can choose a branch or commit. But.. why?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243593/how-to-trigger-a-build-only-if-changes-happen-on-particular-set-of-files, I have a comment in peritus' answer