# Bitbucket to trigger a build on Jenkins when a specific folder has changed

Tags: jenkins, triggers, bitbucket, webhooks

I have used buildbot v0.8.8 for years, but think it is time to update to something more modern, and my research indicates that I should use Jenkins.
In buildbot I could pretty easily filter on a specific folder that has changed in the repository, but I can't figure out how to do the same in Jenkins / bitbucket.

I have successfully set up the bitbucket plugin in Jenkins and a webhook in bitbucket that will trigger Jenkins to start a build whenever there is a new commit on bitbucket.

But I use just one repository for several components (FW, GUI, etc), with dependencies, and would like to trigger different builds depending on which folder has changed.
I can't figure out how this should be done, at least not without polling bitbucket.

Any advice on how to solve it, or another way to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to trigger a build only if changes happen on particular set of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243593/how-to-trigger-a-build-only-if-changes-happen-on-particular-set-of-files)

Comment: Thanks @NoamHelmer , not as elegant as I hoped, but this answer have potential to work:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/66534744/3507638